# How do I extract the boot image from my ROM on my phone to modify with magisk?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader, rom, magisk

I am trying to root my phone and I need to extract the boot img from the ROM on my phone preferably using the phone itself. Then I will modify the boot img with magisk.

How can I extract the boot image and save it on my phone?

Comment: The easiest way is usually to download a firmware update for your device and extract boot image. Have you already  unlocked bootloader?

Comment: please provide link or at least mention phone model